# Can't reinstall php7.3 on debian

Tags: php, linux, debian

For some reason, my php cli switched to 5.6.40 instead of the 7.2 version that I had before. Then I was unable to restart apache2, so I tried to `apt purge` php7 & php5 to reinstall them.

But now, I only have this error:

[image]

(sorry for the French, it says packages have unsatisfied dependencies).  How can I clean it ?

I have already tried the following commands :

```
apt-get -f install
apt-get clean
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to purge comlete php7.3:

```
sudo apt-get remove -y --purge php7.3*
```

add repository (if not exist):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
```

install dependents

```
sudo apt install php libapache2-mod-php
```

if you have apache:

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

if you have nginx:

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

install php:

```
sudo apt install php-fpm
```

check php:

```
sudo service php7.3-fpm status
```

Comment: Hi, i've already done this, and it still pop the same error as I showed in the first post wheneven i try to install it